# Wopi Office 365 implementation on local server

Tags: php, ms-wopi

I have a web application where users store their Office 365 files. We are implementing WOPI protocol to view and edit office files on-line, with office apps embedded in HTML template, using PHP and WOPI. Is this possible to do with the files stored on local server or do they need to be from the Microsoft cloud?
And is there some good resource for Office 365 implementation using WOPI and PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're implementing your own WOPI server then the files can be stored virtually anywhere. The WOPI app serves as a proxy between the WOPI client (Office Online / Office 365) and the file storage.
I'm not aware of any example PHP implementation of WOPI. However, the official documentation is superb and should be sufficient:

- [Integrating with Office Online](http://wopi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
- [WOPI REST reference](http://wopi.readthedocs.io/projects/wopirest/en/latest/)

And then there are several sample implementations on [GitHub](https://github.com/topics/wopi).